# Methods of an object which implements a protocol I've created aren't called

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I've created a protocol to manage data source updates.

but invoking methods of the object which implements the protocol won't work...

I've checked if the objects conforms to the protocol with: `conformsToProtocol`

and the result is no although in the header of the object's class i've declared the protocol:

```
 @interface MyClass : NSObject <DataSourceProtocol> 
 {
     ...
```

and implemented the methods...

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "won't work". Do you get an error message somewhere?

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the code you’re using to check protocol conformance?

Comment: Thank you, I won't work I mean that the methods aren't being called, the code is: `if ([segmentedViewController.myclass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(EventsDataSourceProtocol)]) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you forget to point the `DataSourceProtocol` to the viewController.

Something like this in viewController:

`_tableView.dataSource = self;`

I can't comment the question, so I make above as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the connection to tableView? I don't mean a tableViewDataSource...

Comment: @Assaf b, I just take tableViewDataSource as an example. Here, maybe `MyClassObject.DataSourceProtocol`.